# c++ - Need help parsing a convoluted file

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, csv

[Setup]
There are three data files (csv – space delimited).

Each file, and each line in that file, represents a data that will be used.

Line 1 of each file makes subset_1, Line 2 of each file makes subset_2 and so on until you have four subsets. Then you have a full data set consisting of lines 1~4 in each file.

Since there are 16 lines in each file and each data set consists of 4 lines.... there is a total of four datasets to be dealt with.

What happens now is that each line of data for each file is run through the parser.

1. Line 1 (all three files) – subset_1
2. The percentage difference between multiple points is calculated.
3. The percentage difference generated from step one is turned into an absolute value
4. The non-absolute value, from step one, is set as the non-absolute subtotal
5. The absolute value, from step two, is set as the absolute subtotal.
6. Line 2 (all three files) – subset_2
7. The percentage difference between multiple points is calculated.
8. The percentage difference generated from step one is turned into an absolute value
9. The non-absolute value, from step one, is added to the non-absolute subtotal
10. The absolute value, from step two, is added to the absolute subtotal.
    …
    The same thing is done for lines 3 and 4. After line four you have dataset 1 non-absolute/absolute totals
    …
11. Line 5 (all three files) – subset_5
12. repeat all the same steps you did previously for subsets_1~4
    …
13. Repeat again and again until all sixteen lines have been read and four datasets have been created.

At present all of the above steps are working fine.

[What I am trying to do]

For each full data set that is created I want to output this dataset to an array so that I can use this data in more math/calculations. I have tried and succeeded at putting the data into an array, however, getting the data out of an array is not so easy because of one reason – a decimal point. Column 1 and column 2 of each data file contains a number with a decimal point. I cannot figure out how to get the data out of the array that I put it into because I don't know how :(
Can someone help me get this working?

XXX WORKING FILES XXX

Statistics_BOB_1400MHz.csv _http://pastebin.com/9xXZDSxQ

Statistics_BOB_1700MHz.csv _http://pastebin.com/a6yGcv6Z

Statistics_BOB_2300MHz.csv _http://pastebin.com/tnGKwAyB

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 30, 2015
 *      Author: youngc
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


//step info & names for the raw data array
struct stepData
{
    // The following letters correspond to the Columns in the spread sheet
                                                        // ""   0 <-- Does not exist
    double VEUP;                                        // A    1
    double VEDOWN;                                      // B    2
    string info;                                        // C    3
    int group;                                          // D    4
    int step;                                           // E    5
    double pwr;//measured chip power from Arduino       // F    6
    double calcDynPwr;                                  // G    7
    double calcChipPwr;                                 // H    8
    double estDynErr;                                   // I    9
    double estChipPwr;                                  // J    10
    double estDynErrAbs;                                // K    11
    double estChipErrAbs;                               // L    12
    string staP5PH; // Place Holder                 // M    13
    double staP5;                                   // N    14
    string dynP5PH; // Place Holder                 // O    15
    double dynP5;                                   // P    16
    string chipP5PH; // Place Holder                // Q    17
    double chipP5;                                  // R    18
    string staP4PH; // Place Holder                 // S    19
    double staP4;                                   // T    20
    string dynP4PH; // Place Holder                 // U    21
    double dynP4;                                   // V    22
    string chipP4PH; // Place Holder                // W    23
    double chipP4;                                  // X    24
    string staP3PH; // Place Holder                 // Y    25
    double staP3;                                   // Z    26
    string dynP3PH; // Place Holder                 // AA   27
    double dynP3;                                   // AB   28
    string chipP3PH; // Place Holder                // AC   29
    double chipP3;                                  // AD   30
    string staP2PH; // Place Holder                 // AE   31
    double staP2;                                   // AF   32
    string dynP2PH;// Place Holder                  // AG   33
    double dynP2;                                   // AH   34
    string chipP2PH; // Place Holder                // AI   35
    double chipP2;                                  // AJ   36
    string staP1PH; // Place Holder                 // AK   37
    double staP1;                                   // AL   38
    string dynP1PH; // Place Holder                 // AM   39
    double dynP1;                                   // AN   40
    string chipP1PH; // Place Holder                // AO   41
    double chipP1;                                  // AP   42
    double chipEnergyMeasure;                           // AQ   43
    double chipEnergy5;                                 // AR   44
    double chipEnergy4;                                 // AS   45
    double chipEnergy3;                                 // AT   46
    double chipEnergy2;                                 // AU   47
    double chipEnergy1;                                 // AV   48
    double junk1;                                       // AW   49
    double junk2;                                       // AX   50
};


// There are 48 variables
// Split the line up into an array, 0 - 50 variables starting at 0, Array Size = 51
stepData columnData1, columnData2, columnData3;

// String variable names
string fileData1, fileData2, fileData3;

// Needed for the file.open
ifstream inputFile1, inputFile2, inputFile3;


int main ()
{
    // variable name for the number of rows in a spread sheet
    int numLines;
    int numLines1=0, numLines2=0, numLines3=0;
    int rowsCount=0, dataSetCount=0;
    int i, j;

    // Open one of the files to get the number of lines that you will be working with
    inputFile1.open("Statistics_BOB_1400MHz.csv");
    inputFile2.open("Statistics_BOB_1700MHz.csv");
    inputFile3.open("Statistics_BOB_2300MHz.csv");

    // Make sure that all of the input files have the same number of lines
    if ( inputFile1.is_open() )
    {
        //cout << "Opening the " << inputFile_1 << "file \n";
        while (getline (inputFile1, fileData1))
            {
                numLines1++;
            }
    }
    // Close the file
    inputFile1.close();


    //**********
    numLines = numLines1;
    //**********


    if ( inputFile2.is_open() )
    {
        //cout << "Opening the " << inputFile_2 << "file \n";
        while (getline (inputFile2, fileData2))
            {
                numLines2++;
            }
    }
    // Close the file
    inputFile2.close();


    if ( inputFile3.is_open() )
    {
        //cout << "Opening the " << inputFile_3 << "file \n";
        while (getline (inputFile3, fileData3))
            {
                numLines3++;
            }
    }
    // Close the file
    inputFile3.close();

    cout << "What is the row count for each file of input" << "\n";
    cout << "*************************************************\n";
    cout << "***** The rowCount_1 is " << numLines1 << " *****\n";
    cout << "***** The rowCount_2 is " << numLines2 << " *****\n";
    cout << "***** The rowCount_3 is " << numLines3 << " *****\n";
    cout << "*************************************************\n\n";

    //cout << "Start int main()" << "\n";

    // Working variable names (data imported from each line)
    double mesChip[17][11][11][4][4];
    double estChip[17][11][11][4][4];
    // Create array variable names
    double diffChip[17][5][5][4][4];                    // find the difference in power
    double absDiffChip[17][5][5][4][4];             // find the absolute difference in power
    double sumDiffChip[17][5][5][4][4];             // sum up the differences in power
    double absSumDiffChip[17][5][5][4][4];          // sum up the absolute differences in power


    // Open each results file and iterate import the data from each line of the file.
    inputFile1.open("Statistics_BOB_1400MHz.csv");
    inputFile2.open("Statistics_BOB_1700MHz.csv");
    inputFile3.open("Statistics_BOB_2300MHz.csv");


    //cout << "Start line by line import (loop)\n" << endl;
    // Iterate through each line of all five files to put
    // the data, of each line, into a raw data array

    for (rowsCount=1; rowsCount <=16; rowsCount++)
    {
        cout << "\n ***** Starting rowsCount = " << rowsCount << "*****\n\n";

        //DEBUG

        //DEBUG

            //cout << "\n ***** dataSetCount = " << dataSetCount << "*****\n\n";
            //cout << "import file 1" << "\n";
            // Iterate through the file
            if ( inputFile1.is_open() )
            {
                inputFile1 >>
                //columnData1 <<-- does not exist
                columnData1.VEUP >>
                columnData1.VEDOWN >>
                columnData1.info >>
                columnData1.group >>
                columnData1.step >>
                columnData1.pwr >>
                columnData1.calcDynPwr >>
                columnData1.calcChipPwr >>
                columnData1.estDynErr >>
                columnData1.estChipPwr >>
                columnData1.estDynErrAbs >>
                columnData1.estChipErrAbs >>
                columnData1.staP5PH >>
                columnData1.staP5 >>
                columnData1.dynP5PH >>
                columnData1.dynP5 >>
                columnData1.chipP5PH >>
                columnData1.chipP5 >>
                columnData1.staP4PH >>
                columnData1.staP4 >>
                columnData1.dynP4PH >>
                columnData1.dynP4 >>
                columnData1.chipP4PH >>
                columnData1.chipP4 >>
                columnData1.staP3PH >>
                columnData1.staP3 >>
                columnData1.dynP3PH >>
                columnData1.dynP3 >>
                columnData1.chipP3PH >>
                columnData1.chipP3 >>
                columnData1.staP2PH >>
                columnData1.staP2 >>
                columnData1.dynP2PH >>
                columnData1.dynP2 >>
                columnData1.chipP2PH >>
                columnData1.chipP2 >>
                columnData1.staP1PH >>
                columnData1.staP1 >>
                columnData1.dynP1PH >>
                columnData1.dynP1 >>
                columnData1.chipP1PH >>
                columnData1.chipP1 >>
                columnData1.chipEnergyMeasure >>
                columnData1.chipEnergy5 >>
                columnData1.chipEnergy4 >>
                columnData1.chipEnergy3 >>
                columnData1.chipEnergy2 >>
                columnData1.chipEnergy1 >>
                columnData1.junk1 >>
                columnData1.junk2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
                cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
                return 1;
            }

            //cout << "import file 2" << "\n";
            // Iterate through the file
            if ( inputFile2.is_open() )
            {
                inputFile2 >>
                //columnData2 <<-- does not exist
                columnData2.VEUP >>
                columnData2.VEDOWN >>
                columnData2.info >>
                columnData2.group >>
                columnData2.step >>
                columnData2.pwr >>
                columnData2.calcDynPwr >>
                columnData2.calcChipPwr >>
                columnData2.estDynErr >>
                columnData2.estChipPwr >>
                columnData2.estDynErrAbs >>
                columnData2.estChipErrAbs >>
                columnData2.staP5PH >>
                columnData2.staP5 >>
                columnData2.dynP5PH >>
                columnData2.dynP5 >>
                columnData2.chipP5PH >>
                columnData2.chipP5 >>
                columnData2.staP4PH >>
                columnData2.staP4 >>
                columnData2.dynP4PH >>
                columnData2.dynP4 >>
                columnData2.chipP4PH >>
                columnData2.chipP4 >>
                columnData2.staP3PH >>
                columnData2.staP3 >>
                columnData2.dynP3PH >>
                columnData2.dynP3 >>
                columnData2.chipP3PH >>
                columnData2.chipP3 >>
                columnData2.staP2PH >>
                columnData2.staP2 >>
                columnData2.dynP2PH >>
                columnData2.dynP2 >>
                columnData2.chipP2PH >>
                columnData2.chipP2 >>
                columnData2.staP1PH >>
                columnData2.staP1 >>
                columnData2.dynP1PH >>
                columnData2.dynP1 >>
                columnData2.chipP1PH >>
                columnData2.chipP1 >>
                columnData2.chipEnergyMeasure >>
                columnData2.chipEnergy5 >>
                columnData2.chipEnergy4 >>
                columnData2.chipEnergy3 >>
                columnData2.chipEnergy2 >>
                columnData2.chipEnergy1 >>
                columnData2.junk1 >>
                columnData2.junk2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
                cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
                return 1;
            }
            //cout << "import file 3" << "\n";
            // Iterate through the file
            if ( inputFile3.is_open() )
            {
                inputFile3 >>
                //columnData3 <<-- does not exist
                columnData3.VEUP >>
                columnData3.VEDOWN >>
                columnData3.info >>
                columnData3.group >>
                columnData3.step >>
                columnData3.pwr >>
                columnData3.calcDynPwr >>
                columnData3.calcChipPwr >>
                columnData3.estDynErr >>
                columnData3.estChipPwr >>
                columnData3.estDynErrAbs >>
                columnData3.estChipErrAbs >>
                columnData3.staP5PH >>
                columnData3.staP5 >>
                columnData3.dynP5PH >>
                columnData3.dynP5 >>
                columnData3.chipP5PH >>
                columnData3.chipP5 >>
                columnData3.staP4PH >>
                columnData3.staP4 >>
                columnData3.dynP4PH >>
                columnData3.dynP4 >>
                columnData3.chipP4PH >>
                columnData3.chipP4 >>
                columnData3.staP3PH >>
                columnData3.staP3 >>
                columnData3.dynP3PH >>
                columnData3.dynP3 >>
                columnData3.chipP3PH >>
                columnData3.chipP3 >>
                columnData3.staP2PH >>
                columnData3.staP2 >>
                columnData3.dynP2PH >>
                columnData3.dynP2 >>
                columnData3.chipP2PH >>
                columnData3.chipP2 >>
                columnData3.staP1PH >>
                columnData3.staP1 >>
                columnData3.dynP1PH >>
                columnData3.dynP1 >>
                columnData3.chipP1PH >>
                columnData3.chipP1 >>
                columnData3.chipEnergyMeasure >>
                columnData3.chipEnergy5 >>
                columnData3.chipEnergy4 >>
                columnData3.chipEnergy3 >>
                columnData3.chipEnergy2 >>
                columnData3.chipEnergy1 >>
                columnData3.junk1 >>
                columnData3.junk2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
                cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
                return 1;
            }



            cout << "columnData1.VEUP = " << columnData1.VEUP << "\n";
            cout << "((columnData1.VEUP * 10.)- 10 = " << ((columnData1.VEUP * 10.)-10);
            int VEUPLOOP = (int)(columnData1.VEUP * 10.) - 10;
            cout << "VEUPLOOP = " << VEUPLOOP << "\n";


            cout << "columnData1.VEDOWN = " << columnData1.VEDOWN << "\n";
            cout << "((columnData1.VEUP * 10.)- 10 = " << ((columnData1.VEUP * 10.)-10);
            int VEDOWNLOOP = (int)(columnData1.VEDOWN * 10.) - 10;
            cout << "VEDOWNLOOP = " << VEDOWNLOOP << "\n";


            //cout << "\n\nStart data calculations, VEUPLOOP, VEDOWNLOOP" << "\n\n";
            // retrieve the relevant line data from the array
            // -- Arduino measured power
            mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][1] = columnData1.calcChipPwr;
            mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][2] = columnData2.calcChipPwr;
            mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][3] = columnData3.calcChipPwr;

            // --  projected power data
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][1] = columnData1.chipP1;
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][1] = columnData2.chipP1;
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][1] = columnData3.chipP1;

            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][2] = columnData1.chipP2;
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][2] = columnData2.chipP2;
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][2] = columnData3.chipP2;

            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][3] = columnData1.chipP3;
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][3] = columnData2.chipP3;
            estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][3] = columnData3.chipP3;

            cout << "\nFrequency 1" << "\n";
            cout << "mesChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][1][1] = " << mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][1] << " <<--\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][1][1] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][1] << "\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][2][1] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][1] << "\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][3][1] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][1] << "\n";

            cout << "\nFrequency 2" << "\n";
            cout << "mesChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][2][2] = " << mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][2] << " <<--\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][1][2] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][2] << "\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][2][2] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][2] << "\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][3][2] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][2] << "\n";

            cout << "\nFrequency 3" << "\n";
            cout << "mesChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][3][3] = " << mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][3] << " <<--\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][1][3] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][3] << "\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][2][3] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][2][3] << "\n";
            cout << "estChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][3][3] = " << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][3][3] << "\n\n";

            // Calculate the difference in power for the measurements

            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    diffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] = ((estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] - mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][i][i])/mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][i][i]);

                    //diffDataStorage[dataPoint][loop][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] = diffChip[VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i];

                    cout << "diffChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][" << j << "][" << i << "] = " << \
                            ((estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] - \
                                    mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][i][i])/mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][i][i]) << \
                            "\t>>>> " << \
                            diffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] << \
                            " =(" << estChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] << \
                            " - " << mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][i][i] << ") / " <<\
                            mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][i][i] << "\n";

                }
                // end of for j diffChip
            }
            // end of for i diffChip


    //add a line spacer
    cout << "\n";

            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    absDiffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] = fabs(diffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i]);

                    cout << "absDiffChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][" << j << "][" << i << "] = " << \
                            fabs(diffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i]) << "\n";
                }
                // end of for j diffChip
            }
            // end of for i diffChip

            //add a line spacer
            cout << "\n";

            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    sumDiffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] += diffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i];
                    cout << "sumDiffChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][" << j << "][" << i << "] = " << sumDiffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] << "\n";
                }
                // end of for j diffChip
            }
            // end of for i diffChip

            //add a line spacer
            cout << "\n";

            cout << "\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n" << "\n";
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    absSumDiffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] += absDiffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i];

                    //int remainder = rowsCount % 52;
                    //if (remainder == 0)
                    //{
                        cout << "absSumDiffChip[" << rowsCount << "][" << VEUPLOOP << "][" << VEDOWNLOOP << "][" << j << "][" << i << "] = " << absSumDiffChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][j][i] << "\n";
                    //}
                }
                // end of for j diffChip
            }
            // end of for i diffChip

            cout << "\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" << "\n";

            //add a line spacer
            cout << "\n";
        // end of dataSetCount
        //DEBUG



    }
    //end of if (rowsCount


    inputFile1.close();
    inputFile2.close();
    inputFile3.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't underrstand why a number with a decimal point would be difficult to get out of an array. In fact I don't understand what you are trying to do at all. I think you would be better off writing a very small 'toy' program that illustrates the difficulty you are having, rather than expecting anyone to follow several hundred lines of code.

Comment: Thanks John - This is actually a paired down version. The real version is five files and has ~7000 lines per file. Basically I am trying to get the "data sets" as i described them. Do you have any specific question that might help me describe what it is that I am trying to do?

Comment: OK well good for trying to cut down your code, but you need to go a lot further. Can you not illustrate your problem with 10 lines of code, instead of 500? It seems to be a simple techincal issue from what I can tell.

Comment: Well..... I don't think so. I put the whole program up there because I am not sure what to do and this way someone can see what I have done. It could be possible to pair down the code but not sure what to toss.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a general issue of understanding indexing.  In general unless you have a specific reason for doing so, you should deal with your arrays as zero-offset since that's the languages native representation; e.g. a line like:

```
mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][1][1] = columnData1.calcChipPwr;
```

you should prefer as:

```
mesChip[rowsCount][VEUPLOOP][VEDOWNLOOP][0][0] = columnData1.calcChipPwr;
```

Second, your issue of the "floating point" index.  When you are calculating `VEUPLOOP` and `VEDOWNLOOP` you transform that aspect of the value away:

`int VEUPLOOP = (int)(columnData1.VEUP * 10.) - 10;`

so `1` becomes `0` and `1.1` becomes `1`.  This points out another problem  with your code -- all of your data files include `VEUP` values of `2`, which results in a `VEUPLOOP` value of `10`. Not all of your data structures are dimensioned to have valid storage at that index location, so I'd expect to see possibly garbaged values (or a crash) in calculations involving any of your `...Diff` structures.

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking of this as one problem. There are a minimum of three problems here (read in data, process data, output results) so start by breaking the program up with functions.

For example, with a slightly smarter stepData that knows how to read itself from a file:

```
struct stepData
{
    double VEUP;                                        // A    1
    double VEDOWN;                                      // B    2
    ...
    double junk2;                                       // AX   50

    bool readin(ifstream &inputFile)
    {
        std::string line;
        if (std::getline(inputFile, line)) // read in exactly one line
        {  
            std::stringstream stream(line);// parse the line 
            if (stream >>
                //columnData1 <<-- does not exist
                VEUP >>
                VEDOWN >>
                ...
                junk2)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        cout << "Something went wrong! errno " << errno << ": ";
        cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return false;
    }
};
```

The previous version would read off the end of a line and into the next if the file was malformed. It also did not check any of the reads for success. This one does. Note that the errno is not set if `chipP5` is fed "Hippo". Better error reporting is still needed, but at least you now know there was an error.

In addition that massive reading block in the middle of main condenses into

```
if (!(columnData1.readin(inputFile1) &&
      columnData2.readin(inputFile2) &&
      columnData3.readin(inputFile3)))
{
    return -1;
}
```

If you have a bug in the input, you now have only one place to look. Not three or five or 7000. Also lost about a hundred lines of code.

You can probably do the same with most if not all of your calculation and output code.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a while and some help from a co-worker, here a solution that works.

```
for (int x = 0; x <=rowsCount; x +=dataGroupSize)
{
    double sum_err[6][6];

    // set(reset) the error to zero
    double grp_err = 0.;

    // set the array contents to zero
    for (i = 1; i <= testFreqs; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= testFreqs; j++)
        {
            sum_err[i][j] = 0.;
        }
    }

    //
    for (int y = 0; y < dataGroupSize; y++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= testFreqs; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= testFreqs; j++)
            {
                sum_err[i][j] += diffChip[x+y][i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= testFreqs; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= testFreqs; j++)
        {
            grp_err += (sum_err[i][j]/dataGroupSize);
            if (i ==testFreqs && j==testFreqs)
            {
                avgErrFile << veup_array[x] << "," << vedown_array[x] << ",grp_err," << (grp_err/25) << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}


// Calculate absolute data
for (int x = 1; x <=rowsCount; x +=dataGroupSize)
{
    double sum_err_abs[6][6];
    double grp_err_abs = 0.;

    for (i = 1; i <= testFreqs; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= testFreqs; j++)
        {
            sum_err_abs[i][j] = 0.;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < dataGroupSize; y++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= testFreqs; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= testFreqs; j++)
            {
                sum_err_abs[i][j] += absDiffChip[x+y][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= testFreqs; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= testFreqs; j++)
        {
            grp_err_abs += (sum_err_abs[i][j]/dataGroupSize);
            if (i ==testFreqs && j==testFreqs)
            {
                absAvgErrFile << veup_array[x] << "," << vedown_array[x] << ",grp_err_abs," << (grp_err_abs/25) << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```